# If door A has a 2/3 chance of winning and door B has a 1/3 chance of winning, and I pick a door at random, what's the probability of winning?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

If I pick Door A i have a 2/3 chance of winning

If I pick Door B i have 1/3 chance

if I flip a fair coin where heads means I pick A and tails means I pick B

is my probability of winning now 1/2*2/3 =1/3 after flipping the coin?
or am i wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  Your probability of winning is now $\frac 12 \times \frac 23 + \frac 12 \times \frac 13 = \frac 12$

Comment: why? do you add 1/2*1/3  could you pls explain

Comment: Because there are two ways to win.  Either you get heads and win with door $A$ (which has probability $\frac 12 \times \frac 23$), or you get tails and win with door $B$ (which has probability $\frac 12 \times \frac 13$).  The probability of one or the other occurring (since they can't happen at the same time) is just the sum of these probabilities.

Comment: so i can just look at it like you can either win or lose

Comment: so we have to look at our chances of winning and losing and then add it up

Comment: Hmm, what you said doesn't quite make sense.  You can either win or lose, so if you added up your chances of winning and losing you would get $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it depends on flipping a coin, why don't you take the average of 2/3 and 1/3?

Comment: why do you take the average of the 2

Comment: Because both probabilities have equal chance of occuring (being a half) although Omnomnomnom approach is statistically better. Factor out a half from his computation and you find the average of 1/3 and 2/3 written differently